# how to boot in arch linux live boot

Tags: arch-linux

I have windows 10 and i am experiencing some keyboard where some keys are not working. I want to check whether it is a software or hardware problem. I have an arch-Linux ISO at hand ans wanted to find out how I could temporarily boot into it to test my keyboard.

Comment: put it on a cd. put the cd in your cd drive. reboot.

Comment: You can test your keyboard (to some extent) in your bios. @mikeserv - cd are so old school, put the .iso on to a flash drive - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - that links to an awful way to make a usb disk. ISOs are cd/dvd images. they go on cd/dvds. if you want to make a usb boot disk you dont write a partitionless 500mb image over many gb stick. thats dumb. you just need the kernel image, initramfs, and squashfs rootfs on a fat file system and you can boot it.

Comment: so i just boot into it, test my keyboard and shutdown. After that i can boot into windows 10.

Comment: @mikeserv so feel free to edit the Arch Linux Wiki ;)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - i used to. it never helped - someone would just come along and ruin my edits. it always left me w/ a bad taste in my mouth. anyway, i have written answers here about how to do it. they're around some place.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the .iso onto a CD with any windows CD burning software, this is sort of old school.

More modern options are to make a bootable flash drive (usb).

You have several options on Windows - see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media#In_Windows

They suggest Rufus - https://rufus.akeo.ie/

You will then need to enter your BIOS and make the CD or USB the highest boot priority.

FWIW, Arch linux may not be the best option here. I suggest you either plug in an alternate keyboard, try the keyboard on another computer, test the keyboard in your bios, try this - http://www.passmark.com/products/keytest.htm

or download and boot an alternate distro that runs "live" in a graphical desktop environment.

Comment: i agree. arch linux's installation image may not be the best option for a keyboard test.

Comment: I am using a laptop so using another computer is not an option. Secondly, what i get is that arch linux does not run live.

Comment: Arch linux "live" iso is an install CD, command line only. It will test your keyboard.